# VUE Moment.js não atualiza a data em tempo real

Tags: vue.js

estou iniciando o uso da biblioteca Moments do VUE.JS, tenho uma área de mensagens em meu site e preciso que a data seja mostrada como: "Postado ha 5 minutos", consegui mostrar a data com o código abaixo, mas noto que o mesmo só atualiza com refresh, não fica reativo, o que posso ter feito errado?

```
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>

<div id="app-ask-marketplace">
    <div>{{moment(item.date, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:ii").fromNow()}}</div>
</div>



<script>
    new Vue({
        el:"#app-ask-marketplace",
        data : {

        },

        methods : {


        },  mounted(){ 

        }

    })
</script>
```

Comment: Já tentou trocar o **mounted** por **updated**?

Comment: Seria algo do tipo? https://jsfiddle.net/7afnyr9j/

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do template variávies "globais" dentro do módulo não estão acessíveis, se as quiseres usar tens de associao à instância, por exemplo no `data`.

Mas no teu caso podes fazer isso com um `computed`, ou com um filter se o item estiver a ser criado dentro de um `v-for`:

```
<div>{{item.date | yymmdd}}</div>
```

E no JS:

```
filter: {
    yymmdd(date ){
       return moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:ii").fromNow();
    }
```

Ou como expliquei em cima:

No JS:

```
import moment from 'moment';

...
  data: {
    moment: moment
```

E no template:

```
<div>{{moment(item.date, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:ii").fromNow()}}</div>
```